# How do I search across all sites using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I want to develop an application that displays a search result. For testing I uploaded a couple of files to the default document library in the root site. I can see these files with the following request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root/search(q='Test')
```

However, one of the requirements is that the query should match files regardless of in which site they are stored. As I understand [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0#searching-for-items-a-user-can-access) I should use something like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/search(q='Test')
```

The query is the same as in the first example but the results are empty.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "value": []
}
```

Comment: As @baywet said there is no edpoint but is really necessary to use Graph API? Why not to use SharePoint Search API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview

Comment: Just for the purpose of learning a little about the Graph API and the V2 Azure AD apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today there is no endpoint to search across all site collections from the Microsoft Graph. You can upvote the request [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34684516-extend-the-microsoft-graph-api-with-more-sharepoin)